# Erro OpenRowSet

Tags: sql, importação

boa tarde! 
Estou com problemas ao executar um OpenRowSet:

```
use Planejamento_QA
go
select * 
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Import_SQL\KE24.xlsx', 
    'KE24$');
go
```

Erro:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Unspecified error".
>
> Mensagem 7303, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 143 Cannot initialize the
>   data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for
>   linked server "(null)".

Já tentei os seguintes comandos:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
go
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters',1
go
```

Alguém tem idéia do que pode ser?

Obrigada!